# which DH protocol is safer in communication with given condition?

Tags: encryption, diffie-hellman, public-key

I am trying to understand some concepts such as DH problem and its variants. I have the following question from the book I read. (note that I translated the question from my language to english)

> Assume that two parties are using DH to make key exchange, so they
> need to use a group with an element x in it. Let's also assume that
> our group have large order, but our selected element x is not. For
> example, say that the order of x is 30, then compare DH and decisional
> DH for this case.

In my opinion, because of our element x has small order, it is clearly open to brute-force attacks for DH (maybe I am wrong), but what about DDH problem here, will having a small order cause a problem?

Comment: When quoting something, always provide a link or reference, even if it is not English.

Comment: [The wiki quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decisional_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_assumption) `If it were possible to efficiently compute discrete logs in G G, then the DDH assumption would not hold in G G`